# Why won't this Metapost while loop terminate?

Tags: luatex, loops, metapost

The following loop fails to terminate and I have no idea why.  I've either violated some syntax rule, there's an issue with the self reference in `n:= floor (n/2);`, or I've missed something embarrassingly obvious.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

def divtwo(expr n)=
    forever: exitunless n>1;
        n:= floor (n/2);
    endfor;
enddef;

divtwo(5);

end;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Thanks for the answers!  The actual use case was to find the binary digits of a number (order irrelevant).  Corrected (probably still bad) code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
numeric k[];

def divtwo(expr n)=
  save m;
  m:=n;
  j = 1;
  forever: exitunless m>0;
    b:= m mod 2;
    m:= floor (m/2);
    k[j]:=b;
    j:=j+1;
  endfor;
enddef;

divtwo(5);

end;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You *don't* want to say `save m` in a `def`. Either use a group (with `vardef`, probably) or a specific variable you don't use anywhere else.

Comment: You are asking for a solution to the halting problem, which Turing famously proved unanswerable, but apparently he forgot to add "except by egreg."

Comment: @kundor A couple of points (that I'm sure you know, but to clarify for future visitors): (1) the halting problem asks whether a program terminates, rather than why it does not.  (2) had the question been "does this loop terminate" we would have a decidable _instance_ of the halting problem rather than *the* halting problem itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is wrong because `n` in the body of the definition is just a placeholder that's substituted with the actual argument; in your case you get the meaningless statement

```
5:=floor(5/2)
```

A correct function that returns a value could be

```
vardef divtwo(expr n)=
  save m;
  m:=n;
  forever: exitunless m>1;
    show m;
    m:= floor (m/2);
  endfor;
m enddef;

x=divtwo(5);
show x;
show m;

end.
```

The `show` commands are just for debugging: you get

```
This is MetaPost, version 1.504 (kpathsea version 6.1.0)
(mpost.mp (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004)) (./scottloop.mp
>> 5
>> 2
>> 1
>> m )
```

so you see that `m` has regained its former value after the usage of `deftwo` (`vardef` has implicit `begingroup` and `endgroup` tokens).

Of course the result will always be 1.

---

Your idea of gathering the digits is almost correct; I'd prefer a variant:

```
numeric k[];

vardef divtwo(expr n)=
  save m; save j;
  m = n;
  j = 1;
  forever: exitunless m>0;
    k[j] = m mod 2;
    m:= floor (m/2);
    j:=j+1;
  endfor;
  k[0] = j-1;
enddef;

divtwo(257);
m=0;
forever: exitif m > k[0];
show k[m]; m:=m+1;
endfor;

end;
```

So in `k[0]` you store the number of digits. For instance, the input shows

```
This is MetaPost, version 1.504 (kpathsea version 6.1.0)
(mpost.mp (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004)) (./scottloop.mp
>> 9
>> 1
>> 0
>> 0
>> 0
>> 0
>> 0
>> 0
>> 0
>> 1 )
```

on the terminal.

Comment: Thanks egreg, this is just what I was looking for.  I added the use case to the question.  Do you happen to know whether metapost has anything built in to convert a number to binary?

Comment: Unfortunately, when using `luamplib`, the `show` command doesn't print anything to the terminal or the log, so I have to work quite blindly :(

Comment: @ScottH. Use directly `mpost` from the command line. I've added something about your edit.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea to store the number of digits :)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about why your code doesn't work. You have clearly a typo (`existunless` should be `exitunless`) but it hangs even after fixing it. Also, your "function" does not "return" any result. You should use a `vardef` instead of `def`, and finish the function with the isolated expresion `n` before the `enddef;` (which would be the "returned" value).

However, I can see that you are trying to implement the operation "rest of the division by two", and you don't need to, because metapost provides the `mod` operator. So, instead of `divtwo(5)` you can simply write `5 mod 2`.

The following code demonstrates that `mod` is a valid operator for metapost:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
 n := 5 mod 2;            % Compute n
 label(decimal n, (0,0)); % Show its value as part of the figure
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

The resulting pdf shows "1".

Comment: The original function (assuming it worked) is just a complicated way to compute 1, I think, as `floor(3/2)=floor(2/2)=1`; if the argument is less than 2 the loop stops immediately. So the only way to get 0 is to use `divtwo(0)`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for catching the typo and taking time to answer!